# Cannot debug on kitkat devices

Tags: android, debugging, android-4.4-kitkat

I have 3 devices that have kitkat on them (Nexus 7 2013, Nexus 7 2013 and Galaxy Nexus obviously galaxy nexus is not an official build of kitkat) all of which I cannot do any debugging with in eclipse. All of whcih were working just fine before the update

to further prove that point I have a Samsung galaxy tab 10.1 with 4.0.4 and I can debug just fine, application stops on all breakpoints I set. Is there some setting that changed that I need to enable on the device or in eclipse so that debugging will work again on my kitkat devices?

I looked in the developer options and saw that there was an option to `select debug app` but when I click on the app I want to debug it still does not stop on the breakpoints

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the problem has something to do with using ART `Android Runtime`, I switched back to Dalvik and debugging started working again

Comment: The ART Runtime screws with my debugging in Eclipse on Nexus 7 and HTC One GPE, the indicator of the line of current execution will not move (though commands are executed). Switching back to Dalvik fixes it.

Comment: Having problems with a Moto X using ART on 4.4.2 not showing any processes to debug via ADB JDWP after updating Android Tools to 23.0.2

Comment: The ART debugging problem is fixed in 5.0

Answer (score 8):

**Step 1.** First of all you need to enable USB debugging on your device.  This is a setting under "Developer Options".  As of KitKat, this option has been hidden.  There are many posts about how to enable this hidden section.  The following is from [http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/11/10/enable-developer-options-nexus-5-kitkat/](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/11/10/enable-developer-options-nexus-5-kitkat).

*Settings > About Phone > Build number (Tap the build number 7 times, you’ll get a prompt as it gets close.)*

Once you can see "Developer Options", then select it and check "USB Debugging".

**Step 2**. Next you will need to enable the "Allow non-market applications" setting.

Once you have these 2 settings in place, you will be able to make a USB connection to your device and (a) upload your app, (b) debug your app from your IDE - Eclipse or Android Studio.

Comment: all of that has already been done and didnt do anything. I have done this plenty of times and only have problems on kitkat devices

Comment: Odd.  I had no such problem with a Nexus 5.  It just worked.  Question - when you plug in the device, does DDMS show that the device?

Comment: it seems the problem is with `Android Runtime` when I switched back to  Dalvik runtime it worked again

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder if Android IDEs support the new runtime.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.random-host.com/blog/enable-media-device-mtp-usb-mode-android-44-kitkat

there is a well hidden setting in the options button in the storage menu which allows for multimedia storage took me a week but found this quick fix online. Worked for all those i've showed it to who've had this issue! :)

fyi i'm running Nexus4 OS 4.4.2 with ART

good luck

Comment: This was the problem I had. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem. Running ART on 4.4.2 on Nexus 5.
Though havent tried switching back to Dalvik yet.

**Update:**
It's a little weird but the debugging is now working on 4.4.2 Nexus 5 ART. 
I updated Android Tools and had flashed the phone with a sound fix post which it went with an "Android is upgrading" cycle on device boot. 
Not sure which of the two did the job but it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Having same problem running at ART environment while debugging, so just switch back to Dalvik

Answer (score 0):

Confirming the same fix on Moto X first and second generation. Switching back to Dalvik from ART allowed me to debug. In fact, switching back to Dalvik alone was not enough. On both devices, I needed a secondary reboot of the device to allow the device to be recognized.